# How to manage component state for TextInput change while using Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-navigation

I am learning ReactNative + Redux(Reducer + Action). I am stuck in one scenario. I understand that whenever **setState** gets called component render calls. Issue i am facing is i have one TextInput. when onChangeText event gets called i am managing user input into state. But now i have integrated Redux(Reducer + Action) mechanism for calling API. once i got success response from Redux i code to redirect new screen. but whem i click back button instead of redirecting me to back screen it again redirect me to new screen. Because of redux store have still those api response which i stored on api success. So finally i decided to manage TextInput text changes using redux state but i feel this is wrong approach. Please guide me for this scenario.

**TextInput Code(I create common component EditText it is having TextInput):**

```
<EditText
   value={this.props.api.textPhoneNumber}
   placeHolderText={Strings.phone_number}
   inputType={'numeric'}
   secureText={false}
   maxInputLength={10}
   onChangeText={this.handlePhoneNumberChange}/>
```

**Handle TextInput:**

```
 handlePhoneNumberChange = (phoneNumber) => {
        this.props.phoneNumberInputChange(phoneNumber);
    };
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handlePhoneNumberChange = this.handlePhoneNumberChange.bind(this);
    }
```

**Actions:**

```
export const phoneNumberChanged = (phoneNumber) => {
    return dispatchResponse(phoneNumber, PHONE_NUMBER_CHANGE)
};
```

**Reducers:**

```
 case PHONE_NUMBER_CHANGE:
            return {...state, textPhoneNumber: action.payload, errorResponse: {}, sendOtp: {}, checkOtp: {}};
```

**Code to redirect When get api success:**

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (this.props.api.sendOtp.Status === 'Success') {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthenticateOTP')
    }
}
```

***So main issue is how can i manage Component State and Redux state together?
or i need to do every task using Redux state only?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an action that resets the process status values, then invoke the action creator using componentWillUnmount() to reset the process.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure where you are currently including your redirect code but could you call navigate only when the sendOtp.Status is transitioning to 'Success'? Something like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps: CustomerDetailProps) {
    if(this.props.api.sendOtp.Status != 'Success' && newprops.api.sendOtp.Status == 'Success'){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthenticateOTP')
    }
}
```

Comment: i did in componentDidUpdate

Comment: Can you include the full componentDidUpdate in your question?

Comment: i did please check

Comment: my confusion is Can we manage TextInput in component state like this.setState() instead of managing in Redux state.

Comment: Yes, in your case you can keep your text input state local to the component and call a redux action each time the input changes

Comment: yes but still issue will remain.do i need to clear redux state of api response when navigation from one screen to another?

Comment: No, there should be no need to reset the api response.

Comment: than one i hit back button in android app it will redirect me back to previous screen then this condition gets true because it is stored in redux store so it will automatically redirect again if (this.props.api.sendOtp.Status === 'Success')